# Cascaded delete does not work in a Java program using Hibernate (random behavior)!

Tags: java, hibernate, postgresql, tomcat, web-applications

I have the following problem, which is not easy to explain me. Therefore, I will show you my java code:

Usuarios class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="usuarios" ) 
public class Usuario implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 3L;

    @Id
    @Column( name="userid", length=8 )
    private String        userId;

    @Column
    private String        nombre;

    @Column
    private String        apellido;

    @Column(name="nro_fun")
    private int           nroFuncionario;

    @OneToMany( cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="usuario" )
    private List<UsuarioPermisos> permisos;
```

UsuarioPermisos class:

```
@Entity
@Table( name="usuarios_permisos" )
public class UsuarioPermisos {

@TableGenerator( name="claveUsuPerm",
        table="numerador",
        pkColumnName="clave",
        valueColumnName="ultimo_numero",
        pkColumnValue="ID_USU_PERMISO",
        allocationSize=1
      )
@Id
@Column
@GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.TABLE, generator="claveUsuPerm")
private int           clave;

@Column(name="userid", length=8 )
private String        usuario;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn( name="perId" )
Permisos              permiso;
```

Then, in a servlet, implement the following:

```
sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) getServletContext().getAttribute( "SESSION_FACTORY" );
session = sessionFactory.openSession();
trn = session.beginTransaction();

Usuario usu = session.get( Usuario.class, varUsrId );
if( usu != null ) 
    session.delete( usu );
```

The problem is the following:
varUsrId variable is loaded with the value entered by a user from a web form.
if when I run the function get the variable varUsrId has exactly 8 characters (the length of the field in the database table), the delete works well, ie, first remove all objects UsuarioPermisos class, and then removes the Usuario object (from the respective tables in the DB).
But if the variable varUsrId is less than 8 characters (for example, has the value "plopez"), the cascaded delete does not work. That is, does not eliminate UsuarioPermisos objects, however, eliminates the Usuario object. This causes an error in the database due to existing foreign key.
Does anyone have any idea what could be the problem?
These are the versions I'm using:
hibernate 5.0.6, 
java 1.8.0_51,
apache-tomcat-8.0.24,
postgres 9.3.9

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the How to Ask page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I tried to clarify a bit more the problem!

Answer (score 0):

As you are trying to map the two entities with a OneToMany relationship, try changing the following line:

```
@Column(name="userid", length=8 )
private String        usuario;
```

to:

```
@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="userid")
private Usuario usuario;
```